# How to convert bit stream to bytes?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, byte

Some transmiter sends infinite sequence of bits:
00100100001111110110101010001000...
(first transmited bit is on the left)

Some receiver receives bits and needs to contatenate them into bytes and save to a binary file.

Are 36, 252, 86, 17 (decimal) correct begining values of the file?
(for bits showed above).

Best regards.

I know that correct interpreation of bits is most important, but I need a most popular solution.

Comment: assuming an 8bit/byte stream, then yes. dec(36) -> bin(00100100)

Comment: I don't know how can this question be answered. You need code? Yes, those are correct decimal numbers.

Comment: This depends on the language though. As a maths question it would be trivial.